# datepicker not returning value in jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Maybe I am misunderstanding some of the stack answers and the docs them seleves but I created a set of date pickers in a modal, that upon initialization:

```
var startDate;

$(".datepicker .startDate").datepicker({
    onSelect : function(){
        startDate = $(self).datepicker('getDate');
    }
});

console.log(startDate);

$(".datepicker .endDate").datepicker();
```

The `.datepicker .startDate` should return me the date selected and log it to the console, instead I get nothing - the date picker works. but theirs nothing logged to the console ...

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the datepicker is set when selecting the date. The `onSelect` callback is called when selecting the date. In your code you are printing before selecting the date so you will not see any value printed.
If you want to get and use the value you need to do that within the `onSelect` callback function.
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

For example the code below will alert the selected value,

```
var startDate;

$(".datepicker .startDate").datepicker({
    onSelect: function (e) {
        alert(e);//the value
        startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        alert(startDate);//the value
    }
});

console.log(startDate);//this will print nothing
```

**HTML from fiddle**

```
<div class="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="startDate" class="hasDatepicker" />
</div>
```

**js from fiddle**

```
var startDate;

$(".datepicker .startDate").datepicker({
    onSelect: function (e) {
        alert(e);
        startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        alert(startDate);
    }
});

console.log(startDate);

$(".datepicker .endDate").datepicker();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6rkFH/

Comment: when I open the modal - I don't see anything, no alerts, nothing - when I select a date, same concept - it fills in the input element but I dont see any alerts or anything like that.

Comment: @LogicLooking updated the answer with a working example. If you still have trouble figuring out the issue, then also post your html code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just a syntax issue, here is a simple example:
http://jsfiddle.net/RZxmP/11/

```
<div id="datepicker" clss="datepicker startdate"></div>

var startDate;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        onSelect : function(){
            startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getDate();  
            console.log(startDate);                                 
        }
    });
});
```